Gramsci and his hegemonic block
Since a few weeks I'am reading Antonio Gramsci to learn more about his concept of historical or hegemonic block.
But the liturature is quite obscure. It is either boring or extremly abstract so that I can't understand it without reading other philosophical texts. Now I try to find a more historical application of these two concepts, and my question is: Has there even been written a book which goes through the history of historic blocks? Like telling human history in sequences of different historic blocks? That would be a nice application and I would learn a lot from it, I think.

Maybe useful Cultural hegemony.
